# MySQL combinar IF y CASE?

Tags: mysql, condiciones

Tengo una tabla con datos demográficos de países (columna *name*)

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| NAME                        | INDEPYEAR | governmentform                               | POPULATION |
+-----------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Aruba                       |      NULL | Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands |     103000 |
| Afghanistan                 |      1919 | Islamic Emirate                              |   22720000 |
| Angola                      |      1975 | Republic                                     |   12878000 |
| Anguilla                    |      NULL | Dependent Territory of the UK                |       8000 |
| Albania                     |      1912 | Republic                                     |    3401200 |
| Andorra                     |      1278 | Parliamentary Coprincipality                 |      78000 |
| Netherlands Antilles        |      NULL | Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands |     217000 |
| United Arab Emirates        |      1971 | Emirate Federation                           |    2441000 |
| Argentina                   |      1816 | Federal Republic                             |   37032000 |
| Armenia                     |      1991 | Republic                                     |    3520000 |
| American Samoa              |      NULL | US Territory                                 |      68000 |
| Antarctica                  |      NULL | Co-administrated                             |          0 |
```

y tengo que hacer una consulta que muestre las dos primeras columnas y una tercera que se rellene agregando ciertas palabras a la columna *governmentform* en función de cuántos años haga que se independizó el país y del tamaño de la población. Tengo ya hecha la consulta en función de los años pasados desde la independencia así:

```
SELECT name, IndepYear,
CASE 
    WHEN IndepYear IS NULL THEN 'n/a'
    WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 10  THEN CONCAT('New ',governmentform)
    WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 50 THEN CONCAT('Modern ',governmentform)
    WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear <= 100 THEN CONCAT('Early ',governmentform)
    WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear > 100 THEN CONCAT('Old ',governmentform)
END AS 'Desc'
from country;
```

Pero no se cómo añadir la otra condición, si la población es mayor de 100 millones de habitantes hay que añadir la palabra"large"  a lo anterior. Pensaba combinarlo con `if population > 100000000 then` y el `case` de la consulta que cito incluyendo la palabra "large". Y luego `else` con el `case` anterior tal cual, pero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograr el resultado concatenando el resultado de dos `case`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   name
       , IndepYear
       , concat(
           case
             when population is null then ''
             when population > 100000000 then 'large '
             when population > 50000000 then 'medium '
             else 'small '
           end
         , case 
             WHEN IndepYear IS NULL THEN governmentform
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 10  THEN CONCAT('New ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 50 THEN CONCAT('Modern ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear <= 100 THEN CONCAT('Early ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear > 100 THEN CONCAT('Old ', governmentform)
           END
         ) AS Desc
    from country;
```

Si la condición es simple, otra opción es concatenar el resultado del `if` y el `case`, de esta manera:

```
SELECT   name
       , IndepYear
       , concat(
           if(population > 100000000, 'large ', '')
         , case 
             WHEN IndepYear IS NULL THEN governmentform
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 10  THEN CONCAT('New ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear < 50 THEN CONCAT('Modern ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear <= 100 THEN CONCAT('Early ', governmentform)
             WHEN YEAR(CURDATE()) - IndepYear > 100 THEN CONCAT('Old ', governmentform)
           END
         ) AS Desc
    from country;
```